# Delete Suppressed Row in Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, row

I have three different legs in my report, along with a TOTAL and TRIP field.  I've suppressed leg 2 as it's not required, but by suppressing I now have large gaps of rows between legs 1 and 3.  How do I delete a suppressed row in Crystal Reports?

```
LEG     TOTAL    TRIP
1        $55      234
1        $12      432
(suppressed leg 2)
(suppressed leg 2)
(suppressed leg 2)
(suppressed leg 2)
3       $34       865
3       $12       109
3       $8        491
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the entire *Section*:

Right click your section, go to Section Expert, and Suppress. Activate *Suppress Blank Section*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4444's answer, or as an alternative use the `record selection formula` to retrieve only `leg 1` and `leg 3` without the need to suppress.

Go to `Report --> selection formula --> record` and write a condition as:

```
leg <> 2
```

This will retrive only legs 1 and 3 from the database. This way you don't need to write any supress condition in report